# How to assign keyboard shortcut for arrow keys in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, shortcut

I am using Visual Studio Code and while coding, moving fingers to the arrow keys sometimes feel irritating and breaks rhythm. What I am looking for is a way to bind keyboard shortcuts for moving cursor.

Something like -

- ctrl + j : moves cursor left
- ctrl + l : moves cursor right
- ctrl + i: moves cursor up
- ctrl + k : moves cursor down

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by following the steps below -

1. Press `Ctrl + p`
2. Type `> Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` and hit enter
3. A `keybindings.json` file should open up
4. Paste the following properties at the end of the `keybindings` file, and this should do the trick.

```
    {
      "key": "ctrl+j",
      "command": "cursorLeft",
      "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
    {
      "key": "ctrl+k",
      "command": "cursorDown",
      "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
    {
      "key": "ctrl+l",
      "command": "cursorRight",
      "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
    {
      "key": "ctrl+i",
      "command": "cursorUp",
      "when": "editorTextFocus"
    }
```